# Set maximum value to one and the rest to zero along an axis in a 3D NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D array:

```
volts = np.random.random((3,3,3)).round(decimals=5)
>>> volts
array([[[0.94785, 0.43955, 0.74527],
    [0.82098, 0.52509, 0.67954],
    [0.72355, 0.16252, 0.03184]],

   [[0.25782, 0.04191, 0.6689 ],
    [0.18215, 0.63108, 0.52052],
    [0.81992, 0.36301, 0.66629]],

   [[0.90585, 0.27223, 0.78807],
    [0.32251, 0.65861, 0.70398],
    [0.21687, 0.20798, 0.33868]]])
```

5 decimals is enough for my application.

```
>>> volts[0,0,:]
array([0.94785, 0.43955, 0.74527])  
>>> volts[0,1,:]
array([0.82098, 0.52509, 0.67954])
```

In the above 2 lines I would like to set `0.94785` and `0.82098` to ones and rest all elements to zeros. Not just `volts[0,0,:] and volts[0,1,:]` but all other `volts[x,y,:]` also. So I did this:

```
>>> volts = np.random.random((3,3,3)).round(decimals=5)
>>> volts1 = deepcopy(volts)
>>> vmaxs=volts1.max(axis=2).flatten().tolist()
>>> for items in vmaxs:
       volts1[np.where(volts1==items)]=1


>>> volts1[np.where(volts1!=1)]=0
>>> volts1
array([[[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 0.]],

       [[0., 1., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.]],

       [[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 0.]]])
>>> volts[0,0,:]
array([0.90763, 0.38579, 0.25768])
>>> volts1[0,0,:]
array([1., 0., 0.])
.
.
.
>>> volts[2,2,:]
array([0.33343, 0.73859, 0.43735])
>>> volts1[2,2,:]
array([0., 1., 0.])
```

You can see that maximas along axis 2 are set to ones and rest of the elements to zeros. Here, I just iterate over 9 elements but what if I had to iterate over 200-300 elements? How can do it in a less verbose and an efficient fashion?

Comment: What if there's two or more elements with the same maxima along that axis?

Comment: Can select a random element and set it to 1 and the other element to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1** Here's one with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
mask = volts.argmax(axis=-1)[...,None] == np.arange(volts.shape[-1])
out = mask.astype(volts.dtype)
```

**Approach #2** For performance, use `array-assignment` -

```
out = np.zeros(volts.shape)
idx = volts.argmax(axis=-1)
out[np.arange(volts.shape[0])[:,None],np.arange(volts.shape[1]),idx] = 1
```

Timings -

```
In [90]: np.random.seed(0)

In [91]: volts = np.random.random((300,300,300))

# @user3483203's soln
In [92]: %timeit np.eye(volts.shape[1])[volts.argmax(2)]
10 loops, best of 3: 56.3 ms per loop

# Appproach #1 from this post
In [93]: %%timeit
    ...: mask = volts.argmax(axis=-1)[...,None] == np.arange(volts.shape[-1])
    ...: out = mask.astype(volts.dtype)
10 loops, best of 3: 90.9 ms per loop

# Appproach #2 from this post
In [94]: %%timeit
    ...: out = np.zeros(volts.shape)
    ...: idx = volts.argmax(axis=-1)
    ...: out[np.arange(volts.shape[0])[:,None],np.arange(volts.shape[1]),idx] = 1
10 loops, best of 3: 41.8 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Using **`np.eye`**.  In the case of multiple maxima, this will choose the first.

```
np.eye(volts.shape[1])[volts.argmax(2)]

array([[[1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0.]],

       [[1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1.]]])
```

Comment: Suppose if volts is of the size `axaxb` then you have to use `np.eye(volts.shape[-1])` rite?